# Present List as Graphic

Tags: html, visio

I have a list that I have created of Servers that my group manages. I have also created a list of a specific type of file that we store on our servers. I went to the list of Servers and created a new column that populates from the file types list. So for instance

- If you click on Server ALPHA, you can see that it has files: 1.test, 10.test, and 35.test.
- If you click on Server BETA, you can see that it has files: 13.test, 45.test, and 55.test.

I would like to create a graphical user interface (web page, visio file, pdf, wiki, etc.) in SharePoint that allows me to display each server as a clickable graphic. When you click on the server it would show you you the list of files that are stored on it (as well as any other relevant data in my file type list).

Does anyone know of a SharePoint process / workflow / etc. that would provide me with this GUI for these lists? Or if this is even possible?

Comment: You can easily do this using JavaScript and some images. If you are using SharePoint 2013 then you can use [Promoted Links](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/01/sharepoint-2013-add-custom-tiles-to-sharepoint-site-page/)

Comment: Being that I have never done anything like this, how does one go about 'using Javascript and some images' within a Sharepoint site? I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: If it's 2013, you could also create a standard list view and then use JSLink to replace the server names with an image + server name that goes wherever you want instead of the display form. Either way, it's definitely possible - you just have to decide which method will work best for your needs & environment.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Create a new Page](https://support.office.com/en-SG/Article/Create-SharePoint-site-pages-0ee31678-ee55-40cd-9f48-ea8700035dbd)
2. Edit Page and add [Content Editor Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/add-text-to-a-web-page-by-using-the-content-editor-web-part-HA010163591.aspx)
3. Inside the webpart you can add HTML. So based on your requirement you can design the HTML content (by placing images etc.)
4. Inside HTML objects (Clickable objects) you can use JavaScript to redirect user to the list where he can see the files for that server. (You can [create views](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/filter-lists-with-views-in-sharepoint-2010.html) for each server type, and use that while linking the content)